# Grep output to file (Java)

Tags: java, bash

How can I store the output of a `grep` in a file using Java?

I'm using Runtime and Process to execute the grep, then I read the InputStream

`BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));`

and now I'd like to store the content of the grep in a file, but I'm getting an empty file.

With

```
String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I am correctly seeing the grep's output. However, when I try to write it to a file, the file is empty.

```
PrintWriter writer = null;
writer = new PrintWriter("grep__output", "UTF-8");
writer.println(s);
writer.close();
```

Also, I tried to directly writing to file in the above while (previously creating the file), but it's the same.

Comment: Why use grep? Why not use a `Pattern`?

Comment: grep was just an example. I'm interested in any bash tool basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the println in the loop that's reading.  You are likely just writing null to the file.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("grep__output", "UTF-8");
String s = null;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
   writer.println(s);
} 
writer.close();
```

Comment: OMG, it's working now. I swear I tried exactly this same code, in fact, read my last sentence  in the question xD.